# Sister chromatids during meiosis

Tags: homework, chromosome, meiosis

> Sister chromatids
>
> $A)$ Cross over during prophase I of meiosis
>
> $B)$ separate during the first mitotic division
>
> $C)$ are produced during $S$ phase between cell divisions
>
> $D)$ cross over during prophase II of meiosis
>
> $E)$ are also called homologous chromosomes

My thoughts:

> - $A$ is incorrect because it's **nonsister** chromatids that cross over
> - $B$ is incorrect because they separate during the **second** mitotic division
> - Don't know about choice $C$
> - $D$ is incorrect because there is no crossing over during Meiosis II
> - $E$ is incorrect because well...it's just not true

So is the answer $C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **C**. During S-phase the DNA of each chromosome duplicate and the two sister chromatids formed get attached by cohesin proteins. These sister chromatids separate at Anaphase-II of Meiosis.

From wikipedia:

> A sister chromatid refers to either of the two identical copies (chromatids) formed by the replication of a single chromosome, with both copies joined together by a common centromere. In other words, a sister chromatid may also be said as 'one-half' of the duplicated chromosome. A full set of **sister chromatids is created during the synthesis (S) phase of interphase**, when all the chromosomes in a cell are replicated.